# Horizontal scroll bar in comment

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design, comments

I just noticed a horizontal scroll bar in a comment of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69655841/8344060) question.

The scrollbar only appears when I'm logged in using Chrome (94.0.4606.81)

I assume this is a bug?

[image]

Comment: No repro in FF 94.0b5 (64-bit) or Edge Version 94.0.992.50 (Official build) (64-bit), Win 10

Comment: No repro in chrome ,ubuntu

Comment: No repro on FF or Safari, on Mac.

Comment: No repro on Chrome (same version) or Vivaldi 4.3.2439.44, Win 10

Comment: Do you have any styling plugins? User styles or anything like that?

Comment: Your font is different from what I see on Chrome (Windows 10) here. It seems like you have something that overrides the font as Cerbrus suggested.

Comment: No repro in FF 93.0 on Mint

Comment: @Cerbrus It seems that the user script SOUP generates this scrollbar. [The Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup)

Comment: I've reopened; please post as a proper answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

After a bit of trial-and-error, it seems that the user script [The Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch (SOUP)](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup) is the culprit. Disabling this user script removed the scroll bar.

The page lists under **Known bugs for Chrome**

> - The [mse154788](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154788/why-are-comments-overlapping-the-sidebar) / [stats1987](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1987/rendering-error-comments-with-mathjax-syntax-errors-overflow-their-boxes) fix in SOUP v1.22+ may sometimes [add spurious scroll bars to comments on Chrome](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240352/horizontal-scrollbar-for-comment-container).  This *should* hopefully be fixed in SOUP v1.24, but since I can't personally reproduce the bug, and since the underlying cause is uncertain (I suspect a bug in Chrome), it's hard to be sure.  If it still happens for you, please let me know!

The used version of SOUP is 1.56.2